# Remove category from phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a phone number in iOS displayed in a list like :

**home: (789)654-1281**

I want to remove the home or any other category that will attach with the mobile number.I tried replace() in javascript,but it is not working.Please help.

I am developing hybrid application using kony.

Comment: you could do a split on the `: ` and just take the second part

Comment: `"home: (789)654-1281".replace(/.+?(\()/, '$1')` prints `(789)654-1281`

Comment: As you said that `replace` does not work for that, maybe the "*home: *" part is printed with css or in a different tag.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with something like this :

```
var number = 'home: (789)654-1281';
number = number.split(': ')[1]; // (789)654-1281
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "home: (789)654-1281"
var position = input.indexOf(': '); // with space
if (position > 0) {
    var output = input.substring(position+2); // + 2 is length of ': '
}
```